# How to make a small program using a while loop?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make a small code using a while loop. Its like going to a website and shopping. i want to be able to tell the computer what products i want. I also need the computer to tell em how many products are left after ive chosen them.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Selenium library for this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
# Step 1) Open Firefox 
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
# Step 2) Navigate to Facebook
browser.get("http://www.facebook.com")
# Step 3) Search & Enter the Email or Phone field & Enter Password
username = browser.find_element_by_id("email")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("pass")
submit   = browser.find_element_by_id("loginbutton")
username.send_keys("YOUR EMAILID")
password.send_keys("YOUR PASSWORD")
# Step 4) Click Login
submit.click()
wait = WebDriverWait( browser, 5 )
page_title = browser.title
assert page_title == "Facebook"
```

I gave you an example of selenium above that might give you an idea.
In short, this allows you to automatically login to Facebook with selenium webdriver instead of you.

For detailed examples and methods, you should take a look at the document below.

[Selenium Doc.Dev. Website](https://www.selenium.dev/)